# Search for an specific string in a paragraph

Tags: python, python-re

I've an example.txt which contains hexadecimal data like this.

```
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 12 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19

09 06 07 04 r0 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 0d 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
07 91 94 71 06 

09 06 07 04 r0 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 0d 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14

b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 0d 84 01 00 86 00 85
```

What I want to do is to look for a specific string and if exits continue at that point looking for another string and so on. Besides, I want to stop looking for that sequence when I have a jump line.

I mean I have a huge text file which is divided into paragraphs so I want to search for that pattern in each paragraph and when the paragrahp is finished to start again doing the searching from the starting point.

What I've implemented is the next but I dont know how to express that the paragraph is over and to start from the beginning the search

```
import os
import re

file_path = 'example.txt'
pattern = re.compile("12.*(?=[90|25|30]).*(?=40).*(?=20)")  # add a proper regex here to match all you required strings properly

with open(file_path) as file:
    tokens = re.findall(pattern, file.read())

if tokens:
   os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: When do you want to change the substring, after you found it and then again after each paragraph?

"doing the searching from the starting point." Starting point of what? File, paragraph, line?

Comment: What I want is to delete a file if a pattern is encountered in a paragraph. So I need to restart the search for each paragraph

Comment: What kind of pattern, just a substring, or do you need positions of several substrings?
I think you'd be able to implement all of that in the example below, but I can't without knowing the total complexity of your problem.

Comment: The pattern needed is in my code

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, a for-loop using `read_lines` to create separate `paragraph` strings that can be queried should work as follows:

```
import os
import re

file_path = 'example.txt'

pattern = re.compile("12.*(?=[90|25|30]).*(?=40).*(?=20)")


with open(file_path) as file:
    # create a list of paragraphs
    paragraphs = []
    cur_paragraph = ''
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line == '\n':
            print(cur_paragraph)
            paragraphs.append(cur_paragraph.replace('\n', ' '))
            cur_paragraph = ''
        else:
            cur_paragraph += line
    
    # query each paragraph using the regex pattern
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        tokens = re.findall(pattern, paragraph)
        if tokens:
            os.remove(file_path)
            break
```

Comment: That's not right at all. What I want to do is to search for the next sequence 12;90;40;20. This sequence is not all-together like you can see in the example.If in the third paragraph it encountered 12;90 as it's not enough it should be cleared and start again in the next paragraph until it encountered that sequence in one paragraph

Comment: If you noticed, the paragraph is finished when a line is empty. I'm thinking in implementing an statment like this `if line in ['\n', '\r\n']: stop searching`

Comment: Just change the substring and update it when it was found? Would that do the trick?

Comment: Yes, empty lines return '\n', so you can just check if line == '\n', of len(line)<2

Comment: What would you do after `if line == '\n'` to put my variable tokens into empty if the sequence is not encountered but if it has encountered to remove a file as my code said

Comment: As you said, after `'\n'`  you want to stop looking for your substring, right? Once you've found the pattern (in any of the paragraphs I presume?) you delete the file, right?

Comment: Exactly! That is my goal

Comment: So there are multiple files?

Comment: No, the only file i want to analyze is example.txt

Comment: I've updated the solution the best way I could using the description of the task provided. I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit?